# Flutter timer error and delay when navigate

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing issue with my app with the error below :

```
E/flutter (15085): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (15085): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
E/flutter (15085): #0      State.context.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:909:9)
E/flutter (15085): #1      State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:915:6)
E/flutter (15085): #2      _AdminSplashScreenState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:wallet_ui_app/roles/ifadminlogged.dart:96:11)
E/flutter (15085): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter (15085): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (15085): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (15085): #6      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1281:26)
E/flutter (15085): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1442:13)
E/flutter (15085): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (15085): #9      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:26)
E/flutter (15085): #10     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)
E/flutter (15085): #11     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)
E/flutter (15085): #12     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (15085):
```

The flutter code i think is from :

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      if (timer.isActive) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `context` in `initState()` method.

place your code in `Widget build`

Comment: Any code example please?

Comment: place this class code completely, so i can change it for you.

Comment: Sure : https://www.dropbox.com/s/3f0757usjqleqhi/if.dart?dl=0

Comment: any solution please?